# C - How can I save structs to a malloc'd section of memory?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc

My question's pretty basic, but it's been a while. I'm reading in a text file and saving numbers in the text to a struct 'Record'. After I read text to my Record buffer, I want to place it in an area of memory.

```
typedef struct
{
 int line_status[64];
 float line_data[64], relativetime;
 unsigned long blkhdr_ticks;
} Record;

Record *storage; 
storage = (Record*)malloc(nRange*sizeof(Record)); 
Record buffer;
```

Where nRange is some random number, and buffer is a Record with values, though I haven't listed my code that assigns these to the buffer. I thought the syntax was something like:

```
&storage = buffer;
```

But I know that's not right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also treat storage as an array.

```
storage[0] = buffer;
storage[1] = anotherBuffer;
...
storage[nRange-1] = lastBuffer;
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to say `*storage = buffer;` or `storage[0] = buffer;`.

Answer (score 1):

Since `storage` can also be regarded as an array of nRange records (I guess that really is your intention) you can simply do:

```
 storage[0] = buffer;
 storage[someOtherIndex] = buffer;
```